# Removing substring from string using replaceAll()

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of this string:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
```

from a larger string and replace each occurrence with an empty string (i.e., "") using this code:

```
myString.replaceAll("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>", "");
```

And it doesn't seem to work. I can remove smaller portions of the string, but when I try to remove the whole thing, it doesn't work. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You mean `replaceAll`, not `removeAll`, right?

Answer (score 1):

`String.replaceAll` uses regular expressions. As such, the `?`s in the string are being treated as optional qualifiers, not the literal `?` symbol.

Quote the first parameter with `Pattern.quote`, or just use `String.replace`.

Comment: I just used replace and it worked fine. Thank you!